# RTF formatting in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a report which I generate RTF format off that. It displays fine on the jsp page or in the ireports preview but when it generates the RFT format, it gives me the "Invalid text height" error.

I have no idea which field is causing this error, is there a way in ireports to drill down exactly which field is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Search for `height="0"`, I had the same issue and in my case there was a *Static Text* field which had height set to 0. Once I removed this *Text Field RTF* worked like a charm again.